# how can i get the section number of a selected custom TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

how can i find out in which section i clicked? i need the number to send the item to another view:

```
- (IBAction)mapButton:(id)sender {

    UIButton * myButton = sender;
    int row=myButton.tag;

    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];

    MapViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapView"];

    self.selectedStandort = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];



    detail.currentStandort = self.selectedStandort;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the mapButton a subview of the UITableViewCell?
Then I would do the following:

```
NSView *contentView = [sender superview];
NSTableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

NSInteger section = cellIndexPath.section;
```

You can also use the row from the cellIndexPath, so you don't have to keep your tag value up to date (e.g. on reuse, reorder and delete) which makes your implementation less error-prone.

Comment: my mapButton is in the custom tableviewcell,i gave him a tag. your solution didn't worked, can you please give me another solution?

Comment: I forgot that the button is inside the UITableViews contentView.
So the cell is [[sender superview]superview] instead.

I edited my answer to reflect that change.